# Dataframe for HiveContext in spark is not callable

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the below spark script:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, HiveContext
spark_context = SparkContext(conf=SparkConf())
sqlContext = HiveContext(spark_context)
outputPartition=sqlContext.sql("select * from dm_mmx_merge.PLAN_PARTITION ORDER BY PARTITION,ROW_NUM")
outputPartition.printSchema()
outputPartition.filter(outputPartition("partition")==3).show()
```

`

I get the output of schema as"

```
root
 |-- seq: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- cpo_cpo_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- mo_sesn_yr_cd: string (nullable = true)
 |-- prod_prod_cd: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cmo_ctry_nm: string (nullable = true)
 |-- cmo_cmo_stat_ind: string (nullable = true)
 |-- row_num: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: long (nullable = true)
```

But i also get the error:
    `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hiveSparkTest.py", line 18, in <module>
    outputPartition.filter(outputPartition(partition)==3).show()
TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable`

I need the get the output for each partition value and do transformation. Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In line

```
 outputPartition.filter(outputPartition(partition)==3).show()
```

you are trying to use outputPartition as a method.
Use

```
 outputPartition['partition']
```

instead of

```
 outputPartition(partition)
```